# Как сохранить массив между страницами

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Нужно сохранить массив между страницами, но не просто сохранить, но и при необходимости записывать в него новые данные. Хочу это реализовать на localstorage, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что моя функция обнуляет массив, так как в начале функции он объявляется и то есть просто, при каждом вызове этой функции онa обнуляет массив

Comment: вы хотя бы код покажите. А если по делу то можно проверку добавить что если массив не пустой, дописываем даные

Comment: щас снизу приложу

Comment: Вам надо создавать новый пустой массив в начале, только если `localStorage` пуст, а иначе сразу делать `var productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array"))`

Comment: спасибо) только что додумался. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score -1):

```
    function addto()
{   

    var id = getUrlValue("id");
    var product_data = new Array(); 
    var productArray = [];

    productArray.push('1', '12');

    localStorage.setItem("array", JSON.stringify(productArray));

    productArray.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array")));
}
```

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка "править"